# Feasibility of tzeentch inspired species

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, creature-design, xenobiology

Tzeentch, the weaver of destinies, the architect of fate, originates from the Warhammer 40K universe and is the god of knowledge, change, and evolution. However, I will take away the god like attributes and try to make tzeentch into an advanced alien species.

**Appearance and behaviour**

The species look vaguely humanoid and seem to have short stubby faces that sport no eyes and shark-like rows of teeth. They also have tentacle-like hair coming from the back of their heads but also have one tentacle-like appendage sprouting from each shoulder. Their hands only have three fingers as well as only having three toes and possess blue skin.

The species seems to be attracted to gold and blue materials and will often trade knowledge and technology for said gold and blue materials. Other than that, they seem not speak, preferring to sit crisscrossed and think over their “great plan”.

**Intelligence**

Despite being considered one of the oldest alien species, they are quite averagely advanced, capable of simple planetary colonization, and environmental manipulation. However, they seemingly have created two megastructures that make us question whether they are more advanced than they seem. The winged anem brain is a star-sized megastructure that acts both as a computer and an informational storage unit--essentially a Dyson sphere. It is theorized that this megastructure holds knowledge that even older races and species might not even know. The second megastructure is called the evolution machine. This megastructure stems from the desire to influence creatures on other worlds to evolve intelligence. They do this by changing the planet's environment slowly but slightly enough to induce evolutionary changes that cause the creature to become more aware and later intelligent. This process takes a very long time, but luckily the tzeentch have a outstandingly long life span, teetering from 500 to even 1000 years old.

Weirdly, where most advanced species have and end goal, the tzeentch will have some complex plans that will sometimes span eons, plans that look contradicting to themselves, and sometimes plans that will go against their own interest.

**Extra facts**

A recent information agreement has suggested that this species consider that the purpose of existing is only for gaining knowledge. The home world of the tzeentch suggests that over 80% of the surface is covered in water. It is theorized that the great plan has been going underway for untold eons, and is thought to have the singular objective of trying to know everything there is to know in their universe, store it in their megastructure, then send it off towards another universe to either continue its gathering of knowledge or to help out a random race.

Could such species feasible exist, if not, then why?

Comment: Earth is covered by 75% of water and thats a lot of land. I suggest increase you number to 80-90%. In I also suggest to make that "star sized megastructure that acts both like a computer and a informational storage unit" to be a Dyson sphere - that would be more science-based.

Comment: Headsup: this question and few other ones of yours like it are [discussed on Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7736/good-vs-bad-feasibility-questions/)

Comment: Thanks for joining the discussion on meta. I'm interested in answering, but this question also seems **too broad** - it calls two separate species one species. Is there a way to narrow it down?

Comment: I have narrowed the questions to focus on one creature of the species, sense I now realize that trying to explain if a bird like species with one or two heads has essentially ( if I’m correct ) been answered

Comment: If I may add a question - why would this species have any particular body plan? They are described as capable evolutionary engineers - why wouldn't they be doing body alteration to themselves at both a medical and genetic level? I imagine, based on the Tzeentch reference, that a species interested in novelty would - once it develops genetics - become very like the humanity of Bruce Sterling's Schismatrix : turning themselves into ampibians, furniture, houses, space ships - whatever they can imagine.

Comment: Well, think of it like this, these species are smart, like beyond smart. These creatures know things that literally most ancient aliens might not know, so that leads into this, why. Well why would creatures, even though basing their entire civilization around knowledge and advancing other lower species, change their own dna. Essentially, advanced alien beings don’t have to contribute to changing their biology, even if they could, they might just find it useless, or it might interfere with their great plan. All in all, these species just decide not to, even if they can

Comment: What do you imagine outliers are like? Is the great plan a cultural event and, like many cultural events, only being carried out by a plurality or very visible minority. Or, is the great plan wired in - like ants in a hive, and almost no Tzeentch deviate?

Comment: The tzeentch have their own personality’s, but almost act like a hive mind even though they aren’t. The great plan is essentially just to collect every single bit of knowledge in the universe, which is why they seemingly contradict themselves and do things that will sometimes go against their own interest

Answer (score 2):

### Tzeench must be optimized to support the Great Plan

**Appearance**

I won't address a lot of the cosmetic changes like "short stubby faces," "blue skin" or "three toes" because I'm assuming these are all possible evolutionarily.

- No eyes

This is plausible, but what's the alternative? Do these creatures use echolocation, or do they sense infrared radiation through eye-like structures beneath the skin? Eyes are by no means a requirement for intelligence species, but gathering sensory information is.

- Shark-like rows of teeth; tentacles on heads and shoulders

We can treat these as evolutionary vestiges of an aquatic lifestyle, considering their homeworld is mostly covered in water. I don't know if it's worth spending energy on shark teeth or extra movable appendages, but it certainly isn't impossible.

- 500 to 1000 years old

This is plausible given that [some animals](https://www.msn.com/en-au/news/techandscience/50-longest-living-animals-in-the-world/ss-BBWtx2k) on Earth can live up to 500 years - but it begs the question, *why*? What makes extending the lifespan of each individual worthwhile? Even if they have the technology to live forever or effective [biological immortality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_immortality), how does this contribute to their great plans? Imo such drastic lifespan alterations may cost more resources than educating new generations.

**Behavior**

- Attracted to gold and blue

This can be explained by cultural values, or as an instinctual behavior from their time in the sea. Perhaps they used to hunt gold and blue prey?

- Don't speak

So how do they communicate? Any "great plan" surely requires a lot of communication. Regardless of whether they use something as mundane as sign language or something as complex as telepathy, a great plan will take active involvement.

- Preferred activity: sit and think over "great plan"

This seems like an unproductive approach to coordinating a plan of action. If every human that wanted to solve climate change sat on the floor and thought about it 24/7 instead of communicating ideas, writing it down, or taking the necessary steps to fight it, nothing would get done. Even if the entire species has no concept of individualism and an extreme cultural value of progress (which will be necessary for this plan), sitting and thinking does not equate doing.

**Technology**

I won't get too in-depth here because validating each technology in the question makes it far too broad. I will assume each technology is feasible in order to examine how they relate to the tzeentch culturally / socially.

- Dyson sphere machine: stores information and gathers energy

I question that this species possesses information that absolutely no other species knows, given that physics operate the same across the whole universe. Furthermore, what does gathering all the information in the universe mean? Cataloging each individual atom's position and velocity? I do think a Dyson sphere will be necessary, however.

- Evolution machine: influences planetary environments to promote intelligence

This objective makes little sense. Do the tzeentch assume all intelligences will join their quest for knowledge - what about the hostile species that actively destroy information? Would a bookkeeping species find intervening with the natural world in this way to be ethical, instead of cataloging it how it is? Also, is there "one" optimal set of circumstances to produce intelligence, or does it vary by planet?

**General thoughts**

Physiologically, this species makes sense. Culturally, an entire species having a collective goal may not be plausible - but if it is, they will certainly need to adapt their lifestyle in order to support it.

Answer (score 0):

The main issues with this species are the tentacles and behaviour

Firstly, the tentacles: The shoulder tentacles would have to be some sort of limb, which would not make sense with the other 4 limbs being tetrapodal. There are 2 explainations I can give: Either the tentacles are a later adaptation, like a barbel, appended to the 4-limbed original design; or all six limbs are based on a system of vertebrae as in brittle stars, with the arms and legs being fused into a more tetrapodal-seeming arrangement for strength. The issue with the head tentacles is that they point backwards, and wouldn't be very useful. One explanation could be that they are a display structure similar to a giraffe's ossicones (so they'd be sarcocones perhaps?). Though I'm unsure if this would justify motility

On the behaviour: Communication is important, especially when planning things. However, this section have a simple solution: telepathy. There is no need for psychic powers, though; you could instead have all of the species use microchips in their brain, which allow them to connect their minds together into a superbrain, with the added benefit of being able to connect to external computer storage to note everything down